# Notifications Mode is missing in Artha Dictionary!

Tags: notify-osd, dictionary, libnotify

[image]

I have already installed **notify-osd** package on Ubuntu 12.04.

This is what it says in /.config/artha.conf :

> [Settings]
>
> Version=1.0.2
>
> Accel_Key=65471
>
> Accel_Mods=0
>
> Accel_Flags=68
>
> DetailedMode=false
>
> Notifications=true

This is the Artha Dictionary I have :

[image]

## Please help. Thanks...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `libnotify.so` provided on GNOME3 and apparently, KDE 4.latest is not compatible with Artha anymore as the notification library it depends on is `libnotify.so.3`.

The developers are fixing this with the port to GNOME3. you can find more info in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/artha/+bug/791673.

Comment: No! It's not ABOUT icon.
ABOUT icon is the blue button with "i" letter!

Comment: The blue button with 'i' letter is to toggle between *Basic/Advanced Modes*.

Comment: I added an image of my Artha Dictionary above.

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Oh you are right! the default button with "i" is for Basic/Advanced Modes. But that's different in my one. I have a Bulb Icon for Basic/Advanced.

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm using Gnome Classic.

Comment: post the output of `dpkg -S libnotify`.

Comment: This is the dpkg -S libnotify output:
http://freetexthost.com/mvhsxcissw

Comment: I couldn't find `libnotify3` anywhere, so right now it'd be no. If you get hold of libnotify3 source code, remove the libnotify4 which is installed and install the libnotify3 package.

Comment: Ok then, thanks! Please update this when they release the fix.

Comment: all right, i will. :)